# Android multiline message edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'am trying to make small chat app. Now I have main activity layout, where messages are displayed. Everything works fine, but my edit box display only one line of text. I want to make it like in whatsapp, with multiline.

Like this:

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lstMessages"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp">
        <!---->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/messageField"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSend"
            android:hint="@string/message_field_hint"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/send_button_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't figure out what shuld I do. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried to put `android:singleLine="false"`

Comment: @Gleb Tested my answer? You've to accept any answer as a correct if it helped to you, if mine didn't just let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: @Skizo Your answer was close but not correct. Actually I don't remember what was wrong and solve this problem using RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lstMessages"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp">
            <!---->
            <EditText
                android:layout_width ="0dip"
                android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight ="1"
                android:id="@+id/messageField"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines ="3"
                android:maxLength ="2000"
                android:hint="@string/message_field_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/send_button_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```